# Pointwise convergence on a complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $ f_n :X \rightarrow R $ be sequence of continuous function on complete metric space $(X,d)$, which convergence pointwisely to $ f: X\rightarrow R  $ mean that $ f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ $ \forall_x \in X$

I have to prove that $\forall \epsilon$  $\exists n$ $\exists V\neq\emptyset$, $ V \subset X$ , so that $|f(x)- f_m(x)|<\epsilon $ for $x\in V$, $m>n$ and $V$ - an open set.

Fortunately I managed to do it using some inequalities and triangle inequality, but I also have to prove that the assumption of the complete metric space is necessary here. I have a hint that I should set $Q$ in a series, use $(Q,d_e)$ as a space then set a base $B_1,B_2 ...$  in $Q$ and finally define continuous function $f_n : Q\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ that $f_n(q_i)=0$ and $f_n ^{-1}(1) \cap B_i \neq\emptyset$ for $i\le n$.

Honestly I just don't know how to start so every piece of advice will be helpful.

Comment: I think you mean $V \subset X$, not $V \in X$, and are there any other requirements on $V$?  If you make $V$ consist of a single point then there is basically nothing to do.

Comment: You are right, I am just getting started. It should be clear now.

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204157/pointwise-limit-on-a-complete-metric-space) may be of interest for you. My conjecture is (though haven't checked whether it actually brings you anywhere) that it's worth trying the following. For each $m\in\mathbb N$, let $$X_m\equiv\{x\in X\,|\,\forall N\in\mathbb N\text{ and }V\subset X\text{ such that }V\text{ is open and }x\in V,\,\exists n>N\text{ and }y\in V:|f(y)-f_n(y)|\geq m^{-1}\}.$$ Try showing that $X_m$ is nowhere dense (once again, I don't know if it's true). #cont'd

Comment: Now, argue that if your statement were not true, then $X=\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}X_m$, which would violate Baire's category theorem.

Comment: Thanks for help, I will check tomorrow and give an opinion if if works. I just don't get why it got duplicated. I think that they didn't read the problem carefully.